# Find the values of $x$ for which the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 0}2^{n+1}(x+1)^{3n+1}$ converges, and calculate its sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find values of $x$ for which the series converges and compute that sum.

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}2^{n+1}(x+1)^{3n+1}$$

I'm not even really sure how to approach this problem, I have several theorems in my textbook but I am not used to tackling something like this unless via induction instead of using calculus.

Comment: With a little bit of algebra, you can bring this back to a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: It's a geometric series. I'd start by looking up that topic in the calc book (usually covered in calc 2, sometimes introduced in calc 1).

Comment: Use ratio test to prove the convergence.

Comment: can i buy a 0 anyone?

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;2^{n+1}(x+1)^{3n+1}=2(x+1)\left[2(x+1)^3\right]^n$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\left|2(x+1)^3\right|<1\iff|x+1|<\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]2}\;\ldots$$